# How to run play2-mini in development mode

Tags: play2-mini

As far as I'm aware it should do this by default but whenever I start a play2-mini app it runs in Prod mode (so I get no code reloading etc).

How do I specify I want it to run in development mode?

Answer (score 0):

'play run' is the command for running the play application in development mode. Though it is too older question, i am replaying for others reference.